# Pass bash variables to another application

Tags: bash, docker, variable

I am trying to read some values from a file, save them in `bash` variables, and run `docker` by passing the values as environment variables. The file's structure is as follows:

```
DB_NAME=db
ROOT_PASS=root123
USER_NAME=dev
USER_PASS=dev123
```

And the code is simply like this:

```
ROOT_PASS=$(sed -nr '/ROOT_PASS=(\d*)/p' .env | cut -d '=' -f 2)
USER_NAME=$(sed -nr '/USER_NAME=(\d*)/p' .env | cut -d '=' -f 2)
USER_PASS=$(sed -nr '/USER_PASS=(\d*)/p' .env | cut -d '=' -f 2)
DB_NAME=$(sed -nr '/DB_NAME=(\d*)/p' .env | cut -d '=' -f 2)


echo -e $USER_NAME
echo -e $USER_PASS
echo -e $DB_NAME
docker volume ls


docker run --rm \
  --name init-mysql \
  -v mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql \
  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$ROOT_PASS \
  -e MYSQL_USER=$USER_NAME \
  -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=$USER_PASS \
  -e MYSQL_DATABASE=$DB_NAME \
  -d mysql:latest 
  && docker exec init-mysql echo $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

As a result of running this script, I am expecting to see the value of `$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` printed on the screen, but it only echoes an empty line (hence, my `root` user has an empty password). What am I doing wrong? How should I pass the bash variables' value to the `docker` environment variables?

PS: I know about `docker-compose.yml`, but, here, I have to use this method.

Comment: (1) [Quote right](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618). (2) Compare [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1628497/432690) and read my answer there.

Comment: Really need to parse variables in a file that is yet ready ? Why not simply : --env-file=.env ?
Also, if you source .env you get all variabes set.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's working for me:

```
ROOT_PASS=$(sed -nr '/ROOT_PASS=(\d*)/p' .env | cut -d '=' -f 2)
echo $ROOT_PASS 
root123
```

Show the xtrace (`set -x`) of the docker command execution.

As the file structure allows for immediate `source`ing, why don't you? You'll also want to set the `allexport` option beforehand so the variables be automatically exported to the environment upon assignment for docker to inherit them:

```
$ set -o allexport
$ . ./.env
$ echo "$ROOT_PASS"
root123
$ echo "$USER_NAME"
dev
$ printenv USER_NAME
dev
$ echo "$USER_PASS"
dev123
```

Comment: MIght be worth pointing out that that `/ROOT_PASS=(\d*)/p` doesn't make sense. It's equivalent to `grep ROOT_PASS=`. Also that `cut -d = -f 2` won't work when  the password contains `=`.